# Avoid object construction without macro

Tags: c++, macros, inline

I have a logger that is used multiple place in the code that takes a string and prints it and another function that tells me whether the log is enabled:

```cpp
void log_msg(std::string const& msg);
bool is_log_enabled();
```

When the log is disabled I want to avoid the (possible expensive) string construction, like here:

```cpp
void some_func()
{
   log_msg(std::string("some_string: ") + std::to_string(500) + std::string(" even more string...");
}
```

When the above is run, the whole string will be constructed before being passed to the `log_msg` function, which might not even use it if the log is not enabled.

I know I can use:

```cpp
#define log(msg) \
   if (is_log_enabled()) { \
      log_msg(msg); \
   }
```

To avoid the string construction, but is there away to do this *without* the use of macros, since they are in general not recommended to use?

Could inlining the function possibly fix the issue

```cpp
 void inline log_msg(std::string const& msg) \
   if (is_log_enabled()) { \
      log_msg(msg); \
   }
```

or is this guaranteed to construct the function argument (i.e., constructing the string even when the log is disabled)?

Comment: any thing a macro can do can be done from your code. its just string replacement

Comment: Whenever I make logging functionality myself, I tend to use static functions which returns an object that can do streaming using the `<<` operator. Example use would be `logger::info() << "This is some information " << 123 << ' ' << 123.456;`. The object that is returned by the `logger::info()` function builds a string, and when its destructed writes it all to the actual underlying logging system (which might be files, `std::clog`, etc.). If logging is disabled, or the "level" isn't used (debug, info, error, etc.) then the functions just return a dummy object where `<<` does nothing.

Comment: If `is_log_enabled` is a `constepr` function for which the compiler can proof it always returns `false`, the compiler **might** optimize out the construction of the string. There is no guarantee whatsoever.

Comment: If the point is to avoid the potentially expensive string construction, the construction has to happen only after determining the log is enabled.  I usually do that by using a lambda that produces a string passed to the `log_msg`, rather than passing a string to the `log_msg`.

Comment: @DanielA.White, I know it is, but I want to *avoid* writing `if (is_log_enabled())` everywhere I want to log something.

Comment: @Eljay, Don't you think that clutters the usage a bit?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I like you approach. Might adopt that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach with the function will construct the `std::string` regardless of whether or not the log is enabled. Of course a compiler might optimize though.

C++ doesn't have lazily-evaluated function arguments. However, they can be emulated by passing a lambda that is invoked by the function:

```
void log_msg(auto generator) {
    if (is_log_enabled())
        real_log_msg(std::invoke(generator));
}

//...

log_msg([&]{ return std::string("some_string: ") + std::to_string(500) + std::string(" even more string..."); });
```

Unfortunately there is currently no more concise syntax for such a single-expression lambda. Hopefully it will come in a future C++ revision. However, you could of course write a macro for that specific, much more general, purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think the API for a macro (as in my case) is better than having to add the extra lambda syntax.

Comment: @SupAl • I use a macro for logging, and the interesting part of the logging is wrapped by the macro in a lambda, and used the way described here.  Best of both worlds.  (And I hate macros.)  That avoids cluttering the usage.